# Working Excel nested function in multiple cells failed to work

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I use `IF` nested function grade my students

```
{D1,D2,C3,C4,P5,P6,F7 and F8}
```

and works very well

```
[=IF(AK3>=80,"D1",IF(AK3>=70,"D2",IF(AK3>=62,"C3",IF(AK3>=55,"C4 ",IF(AK3>=47,"P5 ",IF(AK3>=40,"P6 ",IF(AK3>=35,"F7 ","F8")))))))]
```

but I wanted to combine result cells and get Award as follows (Distinction with one obtains average 70 and above, Credit with 55 up to 69, Pass with 40 up to 54 and Fail below 40) in all cells but tried with all possible ways but it has failed it only deal with single cell it cannot jump to other cells. 
Below is my data:

[image: Data image]

Comment: You have to use the average AL3 not AK3 and Vlookup

Answer (score 1):

Create a Table in a part of the sheet column AP, AQ:

```
Column AP  Column AQ
    0       Fail
    40      Pass
    55      Credit
    70      Distinction
```

and use Vlookup as follows:
=VLOOKUP(AL3,$AP$1:$AQ$4,2,TRUE)
and you can drag it down $ will fix the references
AL3 is the average, AK3 is >100 if you use it you have to change 70, 55, 40...